# Unknown plant sprouted up in Garden

Tags: identification, leaves

What is this large plant? It sprouted up in new york city area without being manually planted. Thank you very much in advance :)[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a Hosta of some variety - there are hundreds of varieties, some with large leaves, some smaller, some variegated and so on. Here's one that's similar, but I really am not sure which variety your one is https://www.mandycanudigit.com/plants/hostas/. They disappear in winter, but at that size, it will have been there for at least a year if not longer.

Comment: Thank you very much :) This Hosta just grew out of nowhere after Winter ended. It must have been planted long before.